# No Sound via Bluetooth on JBL Playlist 150 on Windows, Ubuntu or LG Smart TV, however does produce sound via Smart Phone

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bluetooth, smart-tv

No Sound via Bluetooth on my two JBL Playlist on Windows, Ubuntu 18.04.3 or LG Smart TV, however does produce sound via Smart Phone

The JBL Playlist 150 is a media/Audio Only Bluetooth Speaker, which has no microphone.

I tested several things.
I tested this from
Windows 10, 1703 to Windows 10, 1903
After Windows 1709, there no sound

I checked if I have the latest drivers installed, checked if speaker is selected as output and not muted.

It connects via A2DP and has AVRCP.
When opening Chrome Browser/VLC there is no sound, when using UWP apps there is sound via Bluetooth

I then checked two JBL Charge 3 Speakers via bluetooth with same setup doing the same, checks. They work.

With JBL Playlist with Ubuntu 18.04.3 or Smart TV no sound regardless which app is used, both support Bluetooth.

Again Tested with JBL Charge 3, works perfectly.

Other speakers which do use A2DP and has AVRCP do work on the same devices.

Personally tested this on 6 Computers.
Which range from Qualcomm Bluetooth, Intel Bluetooth and Broadcomm Bluetooth.

Could someone please assist as JBL Support not willing to test this speaker on PC. They state Bluetooth communication wasn't guaranteed by them, however the box has image showing Use with: Phone Tablet and Laptop.

There website says works with any bluetooth device.

When asking them about it they state was designed for Phone and Tablet, even if the box says something else.

If someone can test this speaker and does not get sound via Chrome Browser watching YouTube, not casting the sound and using Bluetooth, at least I know its limited to my setup.

Please test in
Windows 10 1909
Ubuntu 18.04.3 or above
or to Smart TV which does not run Android.

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that Win 10 routed the sound to the Handsfree Communication Device in the speaker, even after I disabled it and selected the main speaker as the Default device. What worked for me was the following:

- in device manager, uninstall Bluetooth drivers
- search for new devices
- install the same drivers when prompted
- disable the Handsfree device
- reconnect the speaker

You might have to change the order a bit. What you are looking for is for the Communication Device to be Disabled when the speaker reconnects, so that the system can choose the main speaker as the sound destination.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To confirm you tested this with JBL Playlist 150? On Windows 10, 1803 and above. Used a none UWP app, for example Chrome. Played a YouTube video via Chrome, not Chromecasting it, while connected with the JBL Playlist 150 via Bluetooth. The reason I ask,  JBL Playlist has no hand's free device the have no microphone and therefore it doesn't install that driver. I have reinstalled the Drivers most likely 100 times made sure it latest version. Does not work